# How to put multiple style attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$('#header').css('left', 200 - $this.scrollLeft());
```

I need to put multiple style attributes in the above line. The start and end part needs to be intact.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this "too localized"? Granted, there may be reasons to close this, but that doesn't seem like one. Too localized would be something like, "Quick, what's the current epoch timestamp?!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties), you can pass an object to the `.css()` function to set styles for multiple properties in a single call. The key is the name of the property and the value is the value to set. For example:

```
$('#header').css({
    "left" : 200 - $this.scrollLeft(),
    "top" : 600
});
```

would set `left` to the value of `200 - $this.scrollLeft()`, and `top` to 600.

Answer (score 0):

Use object syntax:

```
$('#header').css({
    left: 200 - $this.scrollLeft(), 
    margin: 0
});
```